# Grep using shell script to get files with some name less files with specified name

Tags: shell

I need to get all files using shell script with some name `X` less files with name `Y`.

I'm trying to using `grep -l -v` to do it but i don`t really know how to use it.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you want to get files from a dir:
Try this:

```
ls | grep "X" | grep -v "Y"
```